# The call is ambiguous between the following method or properties in ASP.NET MVC RenderAction

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, renderaction

The call was working fine until I installed ASP.NET MVC 1.0 RTM.

`Error: CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties`

#### code snippet

```
<%Html.RenderAction("ProductItemList", "Product"); %>
```

#### Action Method

```
public ActionResult ProductItemList()
{
  return View("~/Views/Product/ProductItemList.ascx", _repository.GetProductList().ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two action methods with the same signature, and the `RenderAction` cannot decide which to use. You need to somehow make the actions unique.

I usually see this when there is a Action for a `GET` and `POST`, both without and parameters. An easy workaround is to add `FormCollection form` as the parameter of POST.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ProductItemList()
{
    //GET
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProductItemList(FormCollection form)
{
    //POST
}
```

Comment: I only have one method in the same controller. But I solved the problem. For MVC RTM, RenderAction cyntax is different than the previous. It is <%Html.RenderAction<namespace.controllers.controllerName>(p => p.ProductItemList());%>

Comment: RTM? Which version of MVC are you using. For 2.0 the syntax you had would have looked for an `ProductItemList` action in the `Product` controller. Glad its working for you.

Comment: RenderAction() is invoked from the View that is calling it. The [HttpGet] and [HttpPost] attributes are to be used for requests that are coming in from an actual Http request. RenderAction is inherently being called as a child request (not directly from Http).

Comment: @Steve, completely understand. I put the attributes there for clarification on my explanation of separation of ambiguous methods.